# Raspberry P 3, serial port no data read problem

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I want to read serial data from Raspberry Pi 3, I have done almost everything like, I have use this command

- sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
- `sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service`

I have also put these commands

- `enable_uart=1`
- `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt`

I have also enable(No,Yes) the serial commands in `sudo raspi-config`. but I am unable to read the data. it is connected but no receiving any data and no error

here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import serial
from serial import Serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import pandas as pd


comport =[]
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
serialobj = serial.Serial()
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='gray')

for i in ports:
    currentport = str(i)
    comportvar = str(currentport.split(' ')[0])
    comport.append(comportvar)
    
l1 = Label(root, text="COM Port", padx=15)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

cmb = ttk.Combobox(root, value=comport, width =12)
cmb.grid(row=2, column=0)
cmb.current(0)

bdr = ["1200","2400","4800","9600","115200"]
l2 = Label(root, text = "Baudrate", padx=18)
l2.grid(row=5, column=0)

cmb1 = ttk.Combobox(root, value= bdr, width= 12)
cmb1.grid(row=7, column=0)
cmb1.current(0)


def connect():
    if cmb.get() == "/dev/ttyAMA0":
        serialobj.port = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
    elif cmb.get() == "/dev/ttyAMA1":
        serialobj.port = "/dev/ttyAMA1"
    elif cmb.get() == "/dev/ttyAMA2":
        serialobj.port = "/dev/ttyAMA2"
    else:
        serialobj.port = "/dev/ttyAMA3"
    try:  
        if cmb1.get() ==  bdr[0]:
            serialobj.baudrate = 1200
        elif cmb1.get() == bdr[1]:
            serialobj.baudrate= 2400
        elif cmb1.get() == bdr[2]:
            serialobj.baudrate= 4800
        elif cmb1.get() == bdr[3]:
            serialobj.baudrate= 9600
        else:
            serialobj.baudrate= 115200
            
        serialobj.open()
    except ValueError:
        pass

btn = Button(root, text="Connect", command = connect)
btn.grid(row=9, column=0)
datacanvas = Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 400, bg = 'white')
datacanvas.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan= 100)

vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient = 'vertical', command = datacanvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan = 100, sticky = 'ns')
datacanvas.config(yscrollcommand = vsb.set)

dataframe = Frame(datacanvas, bg='white')
datacanvas.create_window((10,0),window=dataframe, anchor='nw')
counter=0
def checkSerialPort():
    global counter
    list1=[]
    if serialobj.isOpen() and serialobj.in_waiting:
        recentpacket = serialobj.readline()
        recentpacketstring = recentpacket.decode('ASCII').rstrip('\n')
        Label(dataframe, text = recentpacketstring, font = ('calibri','13'), bg='white').pack()
        list1.append(recentpacketstring)
        for i, line in enumerate(list1): #loop for counter
            counter = counter+1
            label.config(text = str(counter))

label = Label(root, text="Counter", padx=20) #make a label for counter
label.grid(row=13, column=0)

while True:
    try:
        root.update()
        checkSerialPort()
        datacanvas.config(scrollregion = datacanvas.bbox("all"))
    except TclError:
        root.mainloop()
        break
root.mainloop()
```

please help

Comment: Write a minimal program that reads data from the serial line in a thread, and writes to it in the main thread. And then just connect a cable from GPIO 14 to 15 (Refer to https://pinout.xyz for the right pin headers to use!). Until that works, you still have a configuration issue.

Comment: yes, i have tried it but it gives me empty data.

Comment: As I said, then your issues is not with python, but with your setup of the Pi. Go and re-configure, potentially re-installing the OS, etc.

Comment: Try using existing tool like `minicom` to connect the Pi first to make sure the Pi is working.